# Suggestion on not-constructive questions

Tags: feature-request

I understand that some questions tends to be subjective, like "what is the best IDE for JavaScript". That said, no one will deny it is a question that many people will ask many times. As far as I could read, moderators will argue that, despite what-is-the-best question is valid, it doesn't fit stackexchange norms, but as it is valid, people should seek to find the answer by themselves by reading reviews, downloading demos, etc. My problem with that is most of the experts don't even have blogs, so their knowledge is denied to the world.

My proposal is to start paying attention to those not-constructive, but valid questions doing some small changes:

1. Rather than closing a questions as not-constructive, mark them with a different color, or filtering them out by default.
2. Not-constructive questions will never have an accepted answer, but rather just list them all sorted by date, as what-is-the-best completely depends on the date you asked your question.
3. Answers to not-constructive questions should have more strict moderation to avoid answers like "If you are a PRO, you gotta use IntelliJ IDEA. Period".

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773) Part #3 of your feature request is exactly what was proven to break: "Turns out that while everyone _loves_ those questions, very few are _actually_ willing to spend any time to answer them (seriously), and maintain and moderate them..."

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will definitely read it carefully. In the meanwhile, may I ask not to close this one? Promise will get back to you.

Comment: Just completed reading those 2 links and the links inside. Something that is not clear for me yet is whether the "The Six Subjective Question Guidelines — Enforcement Notice" is still enforced. If it is, then no need for any change, I fully agree with them, and you can close or delete this post.

Comment: The Subjective question guidelines are still being applied (even though the close reason mentioned in that post doesn't exist any more). Additionally, we try to give software recommendations a place at [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Good to know. No need for any change. Thanks for all the information provided.

Comment: btw, since this appears to be your first Meta adventure: Most of the times voting on Meta is used to denote agreement/disagreement. The downvotes you received here are probably from people who disagree with your suggestion, and not a comment on the quality of your post.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Yes, indeed it is my first post in meta, and my 2nd one in the stackexchange network.

Answer (score 2):

Questions that are purely subjective, off-topic, not constructive (to the Q&A format at least) do not belong here. They tend to invite more discussion than answering, which does not work well with the stack exchange format.

There are plenty of forums in existence that are better-suited to having discussions, debates, and other non-constructive communication.